# A question from Titchmarsh's book " The Theory of the Riemann zeta function, Theorem 9.16, page 231

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

I am studying about upper bounds for $N(\sigma, T)$ (zero-density estimates), and while going through Theorem 9.16 in Titchmarsh's book (2nd edition) (page 231), I got a bit stuck in understanding the following string of inequalities:
$$\Bigg(\sum_{n \geq X} \frac{d(n)}{n^2}\Bigg)^2 = O(X^{2\epsilon -2}) < \frac{1}{2X} < \frac{1}{2}.$$

The last inequality is obvious, but I am kind of stuck understanding the first equality (estimate) and the inequality following that. I kind of sense that I have to make use the fact that $d(n) \ll_{\epsilon} n^{\epsilon}$ somehow, along with the fact that $n \geq X$, but I don't seem to get it.
Any help and/or hints is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\sum_{n \ge X} d(n)/n^2 \le \sum_{n \ge X} n^{\epsilon-2}=O(X^{-1+\epsilon/2})$ so squaring this we get the result

Comment: You mean $O(X^{-1 + \epsilon})$? I see it now, thanks.

Comment: $\epsilon$ or $\epsilon/2$ do not matter since $\epsilon>0$ arbitrary

Comment: Yes yes, of course. My bad. Thanks again.